# What is the current status of representation theory of $n$-ary groups in terms of hypermatrices?

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, linear-algebra, finite-groups, tensor

An $n$-ary group is a generalization of the usual concept of a group where the binary operation (2-argument operation) is instead an $n$-ary ($n$-argument) operation. More info [here on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-ary_group).

I was thinking about how to study $n$-ary groups and realized a lot of our understanding of groups is dependent on the fact that we have a concrete linear representation theory of them. I.E. a group $G$ can be thought of very concretely as collections of matrices, and then abstract questions about the group $G$ become concrete questions in linear algebra/algebraic geometry about the set of matrices, and sometimes that makes the questions tractable.

There is a generalization of the concept of a matrix to a concept called a hyper matrix (it's an $N$-dimensional array of numbers as opposed to just 2 dimensional). And these hypermatrices support a very natural $N$-ary associative multiplicative operation on them (made by splicing the $N$-dimensional arrays of numbers into $N-1$ dimensional subarrays across each index and the taking dot products) , making them a ripe candidate for generalizing linear representation theory to the $n$-ary world.

It appears people know about this nice multiplication property, at least according to [the answerer of this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2186738/is-it-possible-to-exist-a-three-dimensional-matrix).

But after digging through google and whatever free resources I have I was not able to find any reference in the literature on using hypermatrices to create a representation theory for $n$-ary groups. Just resources about hypermatrices themselves or $n$-ary groups themselves.

Does anyone know if such a project has been conducted before? and if so what are some papers/humans to get a general idea on the status of the field?

Algebraic Definition:

Given 3 arrays of 3-D numbers $A,B,C$ we form their 3-ary product $E_{t,u,v}$ from the sum

$$ \sum_{i,j} A_{t,i,j}B_{i,u,j}C_{i,j,v}$$

Visualization of the multiplication protocol for three 2x2x2 hypermatrices, to compute the first element of their 3-ary product:

[image]

Comment: Does the $n$-ary product of hypermatrices really satisfy the version of associativity required for $n$-groups? Maybe I don't understand what multiplication you have in mind.

Comment: I am trying to find a visualization for 3-d arrays of numbers to explain, If im not able to do this quickly I will give an algebraic definition w/indices but it will be somewhat frustrating to piece it back together to a proper mental model.

Comment: @AchimKrause I added an example of 3-ary multiplication for 3, (2x2x2) hyper matrices. I compute the first element of the 3-ary product. You can draw an example sticking to this template for 2, (2x2) hyper matrices with standard matrix multiplication to compare that this is a natural generalization of the process.

Comment: A random question not answered by the wikipedia link you gave: what is the actual motivation for studying these things?  Are there natural examples that show up in other parts of mathematics?  It's hard to even start to think about what a "representation theory" of something should mean without first focusing on some class of examples.

Comment: I have the same question as Andy: are there any examples that you actually care about that aren't just groups? The Wikipedia article gives only one small and very unsatisfying example.

Comment: I don’t have any natural examples which show up elsewhere in research. For me the goal is to just continue completing the theory of universal algebra. One can programmatically generate examples of such objects by building a 3-index array (a Cayley cube if we call the group version a Cayley table/Cayley square) and verifying the associative property. This is horribly inefficient computationally but it allows you to explore some concrete instances of 3-ary groups.

Comment: One way to get to a definition of "linear representation": If I'm not mistaken, n-ary groups are special cases of clones. Clones correspond to lawvere theories. A $k$-linear representation would then be a monoidal functor from the respective lawvere theory into the category of $k$-vector spaces.

Comment: I really approve studying such multiplications! For me the important 1st question is how to find such a multiplication that is basis independent, and under what kind of basis transformations. A nice alternative might be (Einstein notation) $V_{i,j,k} = A_{i,l,m} B_{l,j,n} C_{m,n,k}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to invent the representation theory of groups.

1. Linearize the definition of a group, leading to the definition of an algebra.
2. Notice that each group has a corresponding algebra, the group algebra, which perfectly captures its structure.
3. Define the representations of a group as the modules over its group algebra.

The first two steps generalize nicely to $n$-ary groups. Maybe a good candidate for a representation of $n$-ary group would be something that generalizes the third step.

#### Linearizing the definition of an $n$-ary group

An $n$-ary group is a set $G$ with a map $G^n \to G$ satisfying certain properties. You can define an $n$-ary algebra as a vector space $A$ with a linear map $A^{\otimes n} \to A$ satisfying "the same properties." This works because the defining properties can be expressed with string diagrams, which make sense in the category of multilinear maps (or any other monoidal category). For example, here are the string diagram equations that define associativity and identity elements, respectively, in 3-ary groups.

[image: String diagram defining associativity for a 3-ary group]

[image: String diagram defining an identity element of a 3-ary group]

This is the usual definition of an algebra when $n = 2$.

#### Defining an $n$-ary group algebra.

In the free vector space $\mathbb{C}[G]$ over an $n$-ary group $G$, the group operation extends to a linear map $\mathbb{C}[G]^{\otimes n} \to \mathbb{C}[G]$ with "the same properties." This is the usual definition of the group algebra when $n = 2$.

*This answer was very mixed-up in its original form, which proposed that "the elements of an $n$-ary group should be represented by $(n, 1)$-tensors." I've revised it into something more sensible.*

Comment: How would the multiplication of tensors be defined? The cubic definition I used above (summing over 2 indices per tensor with 3 tensors) seems to fail to be associative

Comment: @SidharthGhoshal: Whoops, you're right—what I wrote originally was very mixed-up! Here's a revised answer that better captures what I was thinking.

Comment: So the key to constructing G-modules is that group actions are compatible with associativity, i.e. $a.(b.x) = (ab).x$. Perhaps an approach we could consider is to create an action of the n-ary group, heres a 3-ary example: $a.(b.(c.x))) = (abc).x$ the only thing not satisfactory about this is expressions like $b.(c.x)$ cannot be re-expressed using the 3-ary operation. So perhaps you'd hope to create an action analogue such that every valid "." expression can be re-written using the n-ary operation. I'll give this some more thought

Comment: Yes, that's my first thought too. My instinct is to put no constraints on $b \cdot (c \cdot x)$, so that every group action is also a 3-ary group action in the same way that every group is also a 3-ary group.

Answer (score 0):

@Achim Krause was completely correct this operation with cubes is not associative in the sense required for 3-ary groups.

It's still worthwhile to ask what type of associative this cubical product does obey but as far as i'm concerned finding a "good representation theory for 3-ary groups" in terms of rings/fields we are familiar with looks unsolved or at least not well documented at the time of writing this.

Comment: @AchimKrause's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/376540/what-is-the-current-status-of-representation-theory-of-n-ary-groups-in-terms-o#comment954784_376540).  If this answers your question (or shows it has no reasonable answer), then don't forget to accept it!